# Rank for a specific company for Different product groups Power Bi DAX

Tags: powerbi

I want to show the sales rank of a specific company among a list of companies for every product group.
[image]

From the below table I want to see only the rank of Company B in all prod groups.
The output should look like

[image]

Please note that I am selecting the required company (B in this case) from the inbuilt filters pane in power bi.
I tried writing a dax, which shows 1 as the rank for every prog groups, which is wrong

Rank Group =

var sel_company = selectedvalue([company])

var sel_category = selectedvalue([Prod Group])

return rankx(filter(all('Table'),[Prod Group]=sel_category),calculate(sum([sales])),,DESC, dense)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a measure for Sum of sales

```
Measure = SUM(Data[Sales])
```

Write a measure for Rank

```
Rank = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(Data, Data[Prod Group]), [Measure],,DESC,Dense)
```

[image]

Comment: if issue got resolved then accept answer and upvote